# Blazor Server app want to display a page based on certain users stored in an SQL Table

Tags: asp.net-core, server, blazor

I want to display a page based on a username. I want to give access to certain users which are stored in a SQL table. I have retrieved the users in a list with a

```
protected override async Task OninitiallizedAsync()
     => auth_users = await devicedata.GetAuthUsers();
```

I don't want to have users create another account for access. Being on a corporate network means that you would always be authenticated. I hope I am making sense.

I have the usernames stored in a list.

Comment: This sounds like RBAC (Role Based Access Control). Add role support to your project if your using the standard template with identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following code to check if current user name in the list.

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@if (InList)
{
    <div>list user content</div>
}
else
{
    <div>invalid user content</div>
}

@code{
    private bool InList = false;
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
        var userName = authState.User.Identity.Name;

        List<string> auth_users = await devicedata.GetAuthUsers();
        if (auth_users.Any(x => x == userName)){
            InList = true;
        }

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```